# Convert double to int and keep the decimals c#

Tags: c#, int, double, converters

I have an assignment where i am supposed to create a method which converts a decimal number (double) into an int, but the decimals should be kept aswell.

example. 2,33 --put into method and generates--> 233

This is what i've done so far, and it only generates a rounded number

```
    static int MakeDoubleInt(double x)
    {
        int y = (int)x;

        return y;
    }
```

Comment: hmmm what could be done to a value like `2.33` to make it into `233`? if only computers could multiply...

Comment: hmmm what is the relation between 2.33 and 233?

Comment: How many decimal numbers do you want to keep ? Only 2 as (2.33 => 233) ?

Comment: When you try to put `2.33` into a `double`, what you really get is actually `2.3300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125` (that is `5246693565886628 / 2**51`). So what do you want? If the `double` is `Math.PI`, where will you truncate (if you use target type `int` which is a 32-bit type)?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `double` to a string, remove the `,` TryParse to `int` again.

```
static int MakeDoubleInt(double x)
{
    string str = x.ToString();
    str = str.Replace(",", string.Empty);

    int number;
    int.TryParse(str, out number);

    return number;
}
```

Method:

```
int i = MakeDoubleInt(d);
```

Comment: `plus1`. [filler text. please ignore]

Answer (score 1):

```
static int MakeDoubleInt(double x)
{
    return int.Parse(x.ToString().Replace(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator, ""));
}
```

Comment: What if `x` is `7E-05`? What if `x` is `56.789012345`?